# How to calculate average grand total using total column

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, visualization

how do I calculate average grand total for matrix default total column. Please see image below
[Matrix Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caucl.png)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected output?